# DataTransferItem's getAsFile method returning null for files

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a simple drag and drop file input. I'd like to preview the files (images) while they are 'hovered' over the drop area. However, the `getAsFile` method keeps returning `null` for files. Here's my code:

```
dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // make sure these are actually images

    if(!isImages(event)){
      return;
    }

    // preparing the preview area

    let target = dropzone_overlay_images;
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < event.dataTransfer.items.length; i++){

      // assign current item to a variable to make working with it easier

      let item = event.dataTransfer.items[i];
      let img = document.createElement('img');

      // for debug: logging the current item

      console.log(item);

      // get it as file

      let file = item.getAsFile();

      // and log the file

      console.log(file);
    }
    dropzone_overlay.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

And what it logs when I hover a single .png over it:

```
main.js:52 DataTransferItem {kind: "file", type: "image/png"}
main.js:60 null
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Testing on Chrome 55.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aaand I found the answer.

The `dragenter` event doesn't have access to the actual files. It can detect what files are being dragged but it can't access their content. This is why even though the `DataTransfer.items` object is populated, the `DataTransfer.files` object isn't, and the `getAsItem` method cannot be used on `DataTransfer.items` items.

Therefore what I wanted to do (preview the dragged files) is not possible at all.

Comment: One should add here: according to [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-drag-data-store] (6.8.2 The drag data store) on a dragenter event the  `drag data store mode` is in `Protected mode`. And according to [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-datatransferitem-interface] (6.8.3.2 The DataTransferItem interface) getAsFile() must return null whenever the `drag data store mode` is not in `read/write mode` or `read-only mode`.

Comment: ... and here's a table with all the drag/drop events and related modes: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#dndevents (doesn't help much in this case, but good to know, imo)